# Performing ETL on Non ODBC Compliant V2$ Files

Tags: etl

I am reposting as my last question was closed due to format issues...

I am trying to extract data from a V2$ file format and some of the usual ETL tools such as Talend, custom scripts etc have not worked, These are These are non-odbc compliant files. I have been unable to find a script or tool that specifically will do the ETL. This file is used by a veterinary practice management system called Avimark. I am looking for recommendations about how to do an ETL. Thanks & Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0):

you have a custom file format not supported by ETL tools, so you're either going to have to:

- add support for this file format to the ETL tool (some ETL tools are open source and you can contribute to them)

or

- convert the files into a format that is supported by your ETL tool

As you probably don't have the time and resources to extend the ETL tool to support the V2$ file format (this is just an assumption, but based on your question I assume you're not a developer yourself), you will have to find some way to convert the file(s) before handing them over to the ETL tool. You can ask the software vendor of Avimark if they have a tool available - if not, you're more or less forced to build something yourself (or find someone who does it for you).